# Closedness of $\varphi\circ\pi$ and $\varphi$ implying $\pi$ to be closed

Tags: general-topology, closed-map

Let $X,Y$ and $Z$ be topological spaces, and consider the projections $\pi\colon X\times (Y\times Z)\to Y\times Z$ and $\varphi\colon Y\times Z\to Z$.

1) Is it true that if $\varphi$ and $\varphi\circ \pi$ are closed, then $\pi$ is closed?

*I guess the answer is negative, but I do not know a counterexample.*

2) Note that if $X$ is compact, then $\pi$ is obviously closed. Are there other conditions on $X$ implying that $\pi$ is closed in this context?

Answer (score 3):

I think a counter-example to question 1 would be something like the following.

Let $X=Y=\mathbb{R}$ and let $Z = \ast$ be a point. Then both $\varphi$ and $\varphi \circ \pi$ are morphisms to a point, and so closed. However the morphism
$$
\pi = \pi_2: \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}
$$
is not closed. For instance, the set $\{xy = 1\}$ is closed, but $\pi$ sends it to
$\mathbb{R}\setminus \{0\}$ which is not closed.